# Can't create a dynamic filename with PHP on localhost

Tags: php, file, localhost

Trying to create a dynamic filename with PHP on a localhost.

```
<?php

    // Create a file with the submitted story
    $created_at = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");
    $filename = "c:\\Users\\Kirk\\Dropbox\\school\\CS 491\\files\\$created_at.txt";

    echo $filename;

    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fclose($handle);

?>
```

I am able to create a new file, but I get `$create_at.txt` instead of something like: `2015-04-20-21:00:00.txt`.

I've tried numerous escape changes.  For instance, if I put `$filename` inside of quotes like this: `fopen("$filename", "w+");` I get a file in my main directory called `$filename`.

Comment: another way would be to wrap them with curly braces

Answer (score 2):

`\$` is an escaped dollar sign, which is treated as a regular string, not the start of a variable.

Seems the easiest would be to just concatenate the regular way

```
$filename = "c:\\Users\\Kirk\\Dropbox\\school\\CS 491\\files\\" . $created_at . ".txt";
```